# How to get the name of the user who created a release?

Tags: rally

I have been looking through the rally questions already posted but I could not find any one that answered this, or answered something similar to this. I am just trying to get the user who created a release. Apparently the release record does not have any field for this. It does have a creation date field; that's why I find it weird that there is no way to get the user who created it from the same object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right- there's no built-in CreatedBy field which captures the original creator.  I have no idea why.  The good news is that data is stored in the revision history for that object.

[image]

You can get it programmatically by including RevisionHistory and Revisions in your fetch when you're loading releases, and then load that Revisions collection sorted by date ascending and grab the first result.  That should have a User property which contains the original user that created it.

Example:

```
    var releaseOid = 12345;
    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels({
        types: ['Release', 'RevisionHistory'],
        success: function(models) { 
            models.Release.load(releaseOid, {
                fetch: ['RevisionHistory', 'Revisions', 'ObjectID'],
                callback: function(release) {
                    var revisionHistory = Ext.create(models.RevisionHistory, release.get('RevisionHistory'));
                    revisionHistory.getCollection('Revisions', {
                        fetch: ['User'],
                        pageSize: 1,
                        sorters: [{
                            property: 'CreationDate',
                            direction: 'ASC'
                        }],
                    }).load({
                        callback: function(revisions) {
                            console.log(revisions[0].get('User'));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for your answers. I've been trying to do what you instructed by creating a snapstore with the lookback api, but I keep getting GET errors when calling it. What's the correct way to create a release snapstore with the lookback api? thanks.

Comment: Hmm, you might be able to use the lookback api for this, but it's not necessary.  I updated my answer with some example code to load the revisions for a release...